# Excel VBA - update column in range when any cell in another column changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cells that is A2:H31.  I need to write a script that loops though all rows (2 through 31) when the value of
any cell in columns F or G are changed.  The following is a list of that needs to happen:

1. User changes the value of of a cell in Col F or G.
2. Create a variable (or something along those lines) that equals the cell value in column E of the row of the changed cell
3. The script loops through all rows to look for any rows where column A matches column G of the changed cells row.
4. Update the value of the cell in column D to match the variable in step 2.

I am trying to better understand how to trigger a loop, declaring variables and their value and updating cell values.

Comment: Pls include your code in OP.

Comment: I don't have the code.  I need to write it and am hoping for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rData As Range, c As Range
    Set rData = Me.Range("F2:G31")
    With Target
        Set c = Application.Intersect(Target, rData)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            For i = 2 To 31
                If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(.Row, "G") Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Cells(i, "D") = Cells(.Row, "E")
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```